# Asp.net mvc fileupload via ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

Any code snippet to upload file to server via ajax call? I am using Asp.net MVC 3

Comment: Filetransfer via ajax isn't possible atm. You need to use a solution that posts to a iframe to achieve the feel of a "ajax"-upload. No XHR-requests.

Comment: I dont think there was any reason for the negative vote.. why cant he think that it can be done! Its a vlaid question..

Comment: Have you checked out this (jQuery File Upload) http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey try using this tool called slickupload. Its a really cool tool and handles most of the problems with streaming while providing a cool UI while uploading the file too.. really easy to use too.

Problems with uploading large files of net disconnection etc is also handled gracefully by this tool..

do check it out at

http://krystalware.com/Products/SlickUpload/

Comment: There's also [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) if you're already doing jQuery stuff.

Comment: nice..  its open source too.. +1 frm me.. but i still love slick upload cos my company can afford it.. :D

Comment: does that support choosing directories to upload their content?

Comment: At the server side you control where you want to store the file. Sslickupload will just give you the file as a byte stream saving it is left to you