# Upload file without page refresh in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a question. Which control is better to use for file uploading (ASP.NET MVC3)? Wihtout page refresh of course. And it should work in old browsers like IE8.

Answer (score 2):

Check out existing questions

[asp.net mvc file upload ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780241/asp-net-mvc-file-upload-ajax-post)

[Asp.net mvc fileupload via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914420/asp-net-mvc-fileupload-via-ajax)

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

Answer (score 0):

I am using this [plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

In this link you can see a [demo](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) of the plugin and [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki)

I have done it with asp.net pages, But the concept should be the same.

[Here an example in MVC3](https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3)